# Creating MongoDB linked Service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am having issues setting up a Mongo DB linked service in Azure Data Factory. We are already using Mongo DB connection on our On-Premise platform to extract some data from Client side.

Now, we are migrating all our on-premise process to Azure. So this connection is part of many other things that we are migrating. I am using below connection string.

This same string is working perfectly fine on our on-premise environment but for some reason, not working in Azure.Could someone please help

```
ConnectionString="mongodb://username:password@jproduct-hekrl.gvt.mongodb.net:20007/management-core?ssl=true&replicaSet=Product-shard-0&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to answer without knowing the actual error message but I'll try:

Are you pasting the connection String just as you are showing us? with the initial words included?

The connection String should be in the format below:

```
mongodb://[username:password]@host[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

As you can see, there is no `ConnectionString=` at the beginning, So in your case it seems it should be as follows:

```
mongodb://username:password@jproduct-hekrl.gvt.mongodb.net:20007/management-core?ssl=true&replicaSet=Product-shard-0&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Just need to remove the `ConnectionString="` from the beginning

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb)

Comment: Many thanks for getting back. Just to confirm i am not including ConnectionString=" " in my connection string.I have tried your suggested string. Still getting the error message. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Try %40 instead of @. Like this: mongodb://username:password%40jproduct-hekrl.gvt.mongodb.net:20007/management-core?ssl=true&replicaSet=Product-shard-0&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: When i use %40 in my string and click on "Test Connection" it throws an error message straight away.